# how to make a listview fill the usable screen area?

Tags: android, android-listview

im working on a app that must fit one listview item on the screen. How can i make it so that it scales and fits only one listview item on the screen. I have some code but the onscreen navigation buttons over lap. How can i make it so the listview doesn't over lap?

this is my layout, the id im_MainPic should fit the screen.

```
 <RelativeLayout xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
   xmlns:tools="http://schemas.android.com/tools"
  android:layout_width="match_parent"
  android:layout_height="match_parent"
  tools:context=".MainActivity" >

<ImageView
    android:id="@+id/im_MainPic"
    android:layout_width="match_parent"
    android:layout_height="match_parent"
    android:layout_alignParentBottom="true"
    android:layout_alignParentLeft="true"
    android:layout_alignParentRight="true"
    android:layout_alignParentTop="true"
    android:src="@drawable/ic_launcher" />




     </RelativeLayout>
```

Comment: Please post the layout you have so far. It's too general a question without it.

Comment: Send us full layout and screen shot. When you say full screen do you wanna hide action bar, clock/battery indicator(i dont remember how  it was called) or do you mean just the space you have?

Comment: I agree, at present it's a bit unclear which "onscreen navigation buttons" you're referring to. A screenshot of your current layout would be immensely helpful.

Comment: im talking about the back, home.. buttons that some android phones have

Answer (score 0):

In the activity section of your manifest file, put this:

```
android:theme="@android:style/Theme.NoTitleBar.Fullscreen"
```